# php/bootstrap gallery ,display images in modals

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have gallery in bootstrap using modals. I wrote little script for loading images from folder.

My problem is that pictures don't show in modal there is only blank space.When  I try to display them outside of the modal it works. Where is the problem?

Here is a little fragment of code:

```
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade">
                 <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                       <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                       </div>
                       <div class="modal-body">
                          <div class="carousel slide" id="screenshot-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
                             <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                             </ol>
                             <div class="carousel-inner">
                                   <?php
                    $dirname = 'Gallery/';
                    $images = glob($dirname . "*");
                    foreach ($images as $image) {
                        echo "<div class=".'item active'.">";
                            echo "<img src=".'$image'."'alt=".'Text of the image'.">";
                            echo "<div class=".'carousel-caption'.">";
                            echo "<h3>Highway heading</h3>";
                            echo "<p>This is the caption</p>";
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo "</div>";
                    }
                ?>  
                             <!-- End Carousel inner -->
                             <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
                             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                             </a>
                             <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
                             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                             </a>
                          </div>
                          <!-- End Carousel -->
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your single and double quotes. You are wrapping your variable in single quotes so if you viewed the html source it would be looking for an image named '$image' try changing to:

```
echo "<img src='".$image."' alt='Text of the image'>";
```

Comment: It sounds good , but It does't work , I've tried to echo it out without div tags , images appear but in one modal without glyphicons

Comment: could you view the source of the html and post the code? What path is the shown is the img src? It may be malformed HTML and the browser isn't rendering it

Comment: problem is that I have this foreach loop for loading images from folder and it loads all images in one modal